# MySQL querying failing?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My MySQL query keeps failing and I can't understand why, I read up on it and apparently I was missing the backticks (`) around the table names etc, so I added them and no change. Here is the code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";db_name=".db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);

    try{
        $check = $db->prepare("SELECT `userID` from `userData` WHERE `userID` = :accountID");
        $check->bindParam(':accountID', $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->execute();
        if(!$check->execute()){
            die(var_dump($db->errorInfo()));
        }else{
            if($check->rowCount() > 0) {
                $creditsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT `userCredits` FROM `userData` WHERE `userID` = :accountID3");
                $creditsQuery->bindParam(":accountID3", $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $creditsQuery->execute();
                //Set Credits To Variable From Database Column
                $credits = $creditsQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }else{
                $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userData` (`userID`, `userCredits`) VALUES (:accountID2, '0')");
                $sql->bindParam(':accountID2', $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sql->execute();
                if(!$sql){
                    die('Server Error: 404Insert, Please Contact A Member Of Staff If This Error Continues.');
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die ("Server Error: 404Connection, Please Contact A Member Of Staff If This Error Continues.");
    }
```

The errorInfo line displays: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

So, the database successfully connects as the try block doesn't throw an exception. So I really don't know.

thanks,

Matt

Comment: Your PDO connection instruction is not in your try block, so the exception would not be caught :)

Comment: I added it into the try block, and there is no change again

Comment: `$accid` has no value, in your example...

Comment: Why are you executing it twice?

Comment: Your PDOStatement object will never throw an exception since you haven't set PDO in exception mode.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You're `execute`ing the query twice!

Comment: I want it so when the user logs in, it checks if their is already a row in userID which contains their id and if it does find it, display their credits, and if not, insert the user's id into the row with their credits being 0. Here is my code i've updated: http://pastebin.com/ax4WFSXb

Comment: Well, there are many mistakes here, but most important one is what @Strawberry noticed - what exactly are you doing here? If you are checking if record exists in PHP, then you are going to have a really, really bad time when you realize what concurrency is.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code

- PDO is not in exception mode
- `$accid` contains no value
- you are using `bindParam` instead of `bindValue` - there are differences between them, quite significant ones
- you don't have to wrap anything with backticks unless it's a MySQL reserved word
- you are checking for existence of record in PHP - that's MySQL's job. PHP can't accurately determine if a record exists in MySQL. There's a tiny delay between PHP and MySQL connection (tiny in human measurement, eons in computer measurement). By the time the result arrives and gets parsed by PHP, another process could have inserted the record. That's why we let MySQL take care of uniqueness and data integrity.

Please, read the comments of the code I'm posting and adjust according to your needs:

```
<?php

/**
 * Create PDO object and set it into exception mode
 */

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";db_name=".db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}


try {
    // Replace with actual value
    $user_id = 1; 

    // Pay close attention to IGNORE keyword - it's extremely important
    // and it requires a unique index to be placed on userID column
    // I assumed that userID is primary key
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO userData (userID, userCredits) VALUES (:userID, 0)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindValue(':userID', $user_id);

    $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'An error occurred: '. $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, although, when ran, it catches an exception in the second try statement. Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/Gv7EYqbN

Comment: @Matt142 - what is the exception message and why are you using `rowCount()` function? If you don't get an exception, query is successful, you can proceed with select.

Comment: The exception message is errUser, sorry I just thought it through